# Lint unused resources false positives with new version of android plugin for gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, lint, gradle-plugin

I previously was using the 1.2.3 version of the [android plugin for gradle](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/revisions/gradle-plugin.html).

I noticed that when updating for the 1.3 the number of unused resources reported by lint increased considerably. After some analysis I noticed that most (if not all) of them are false positives...

Does anyone else noticed a similar behavior? If so, any tips on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

update version of the Android Gradle plugin to the newest,(e.g. 1.5.0).
refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182555

Comment: The recommended version is maybe not that accurate, but thx for pointing the ticket, it's the exact issue mentioned by the OP. This should be an accepted answer. (and would actually be encouraging a user with a reputation of +1... @lage)